# Full Name From User To be In Separated Hidden Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form with the two below inputs

```
<div class="required form-group" style="display:none">
    <label for="customer_firstname">{l s='First name'} 
        <sup>*</sup>
    </label>
    <input onkeyup="$('#firstname').val(this.value);" type="text" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isName" id="customer_firstname" name="customer_firstname" value="{if isset($smarty.post.customer_firstname)}{$smarty.post.customer_firstname}{/if}" />
</div>
<div class="required form-group" style="display:none">
    <label for="customer_lastname">{l s='Last name'} 
        <sup>*</sup>
    </label>
    <input onkeyup="$('#lastname').val(this.value);" type="text" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isName" id="customer_lastname" name="customer_lastname" value="{if isset($smarty.post.customer_lastname)}{$smarty.post.customer_lastname}{/if}" />
</div>
```

As you can see both these fields are hidden. This is because I want to create a new input called full name and whatever the user types here gets filled into these first name and last name automatically.

So if full name is John Doe then first name will hold John and last name will hold Doe. Or if full name is Stuart Ben Mackenzie then fist name will hold Stuart Ben and last name will hold Mackenzie. How can I do this with Javascript??

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
<input id="fullname" type="text"/>

$('#fullname').val($('#firstname').val()+' '+$('#lastname').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you want to discern the first name from the last. If you want the last name to always be only 1 word then it you would parse the names as such.

Add to your input(s) which you need to track input a class or attribute then simply bind the keyup event handler to it such as

```
$("input[traced-input]").on("keyup", function(){
    var tft = $(this); //short for thisTextField
    if(tft.attr("id")==='fullname'){
        //parse the names here into an array presumably
        $("#firstname").val(namesArr['firstname']);
        $("lastname").val(namesArr['lastname']);
    }
});
```

Make sure you put the js in $(document).ready() and if the HTML content will be dynamically loaded then add a delegate such as

```
$(document).on("keyup", '.class or #id here', function () {
        //do stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive using bellow code:

```
<input id="fullname" type="text"/>

var fullname=$('#fullname').val();
var pieces = fullname.split(' ');

var customer_lastname=pieces[pieces.length-1];
$("#customer_lastname").val(customer_lastname);

pieces.pop();
var customer_firstname=pieces.join(" ");
$("#customer_firstname").val(customer_firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dfullname').on('keyup', function(e){
var fullname = $(this).val();
var splitFullName = fullname.split(' ');
$('#firstname').val(splitFullName[0]);
$('lastname').val(splitFullName[1]);
});
```

of course this will only work if you are having 1 first name and 1 last name, but it gives you the general idea.